# Wix toolset - powershell script msi creation

Tags: powershell, wix

I have a new project at work, for customer, that require me to do an OEM image creation.

The pre
The idea would be deploy OEM image, it will install, and deploy all software, and then shutdown. Once started back up it will prompt users to chose pc name, select Domain to join and regional settings.
I think i can do this by using a powershell script and wrapping it up in an msi and add it to MDT with no silent install switches (so that it prompts users to manually go through the steps)

Now my issue is how do i inject a powershell script as well as ensure that if this scipt has user input required, that it actually prompts the user to input the data (is this even possible with Wix?)

Answer (score 0):

WiX is able to install files, configure Windows settings, interact with SQL Servers, and etc, but you are working with an installer file. It is not possible to receive input from the end user after a system reboot from WiX alone since you can run a PowerShell script while the system is active, but once it restarts, the process will get terminated and has to be restarted. Unless there is some way to schedule the PowerShell script in Windows such as running it from a service created in C#.